# Reuse same UIView for Left to Right Animation side by side

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, objective-c-blocks, uiviewanimation

I have created UIView in XIB. I want to animate this view from Left to Right 2 times that too **SIDE BY SIDE**.

Below code animates the UIView but this code animates one by one transition of this UIView. I want same View to be reused. Will this be possible? Please see my below code.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:1.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         viewPasscode.frame = CGRectMake(-320, viewPasscode.frame.origin.y, viewPasscode.frame.size.width, viewPasscode.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if (finished)
                             viewPasscode.frame = CGRectMake(320, 9, 309, 274);
                         else
                             return;
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                                               delay:1.0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                                          animations:^{
                                              viewPasscode.frame = CGRectMake(6, 9, 309, 274);
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                              if (finished)
                                                  viewPasscode.frame = CGRectMake(6, 9, 309, 274);
                                          }];
                     }
     ];
```

Comment: You mean you want 2 instances of the view, each loaded from the same XIB and animated at the same time?

Comment: yes that's correct... do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Please add the code where you instantiate the view to the question.

Comment: As I said, I have just the IBOutlet of UIView from XIB. I have not instantiated in code.

Comment: So you'd need to add another view to the XIB, with another outlet, and modify the code to change both views frames during the animation.